# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 on Facebook Instant Game

Tags: facebook-instant-games

I'm developing a Facebook Instant Game using HTML5 and am having trouble loading the css and JavaScript files linked on the index.html page, it is showing

> "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404"

on the chrome console
Is this a question of permissions or what am I missing? all files are on the root.
Take a look at the image here you can see the console errors.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out what the problem is. I had the following html element on the header:

```
<base href="/">
```

Changing it to

```
<base href="">
```

will do the trick!